# Pyqt5 Update childs position when resize parent

Tags: python, pyqt5

In Python and PyQt5 I create a `QmainWindow` as parent and a `Qwidget` as it's child.
All works but when I resize the window the child stays always at the same position.
I need a solution for the child that the position will update when I resize the parent widget.

In the parent widget I have a message-bubble. An the child widget is just a badge where numbers of new messages where displays. If I resize the window, the message-bubble is moving but the badge stays in the same position the badge goes away from the message bubble.

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QWidget
from UIs.badge import Ui_Form
from PyQt5.QtCore import  Qt
from UIs.message import Ui_MainWindow

import sys

"""
    This is my Badge class. 
    It is just one QLabel with 'FontAwesome Solid' Font to get a Dot (circle)
    and another QLabel for the number.
    Without any layout for free positioning (Label over label)
"""
class badge(QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super(badge, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = Ui_Form()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.label.setProperty("text","0")
        self.setAttribute(Qt.WidgetAttribute.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)
        
"""
    This is my MainWindow class. 
    With Flat QPushButton and 'FontAwesome' as well to get the Bubble (comments)  
"""  
class mainW(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mainW, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)   
        self.label_badge = badge(self.ui.btn_comments)
        self.label_badge.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(self.ui.btn_comments.x(),self.ui.btn_comments.y(),self.label_badge.width(),self.label_badge.height()))
   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = mainW()
    window.show()
    app.exec()
```

So, when I start the app all looks normal, but when I resize the window, the bagde always stays at the same position but should stay by the bubble.

I read something about `eventFilters`, but I don't understand the mechanism.

The above code is just the code I wrote. If you need the code which was generated by the qt designer, let me know.

This is the badge made with qt creator:

[image]

This is the window after starting the app

[image]

When i resize it look like this

[image]

**Next Try:**

Problem is always the same.
I have now removed everything that is not needed and only left the part with the bubble.

**test_bubble.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>450</width>
    <height>370</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="minimumSize">
   <size>
    <width>450</width>
    <height>370</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true"/>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QWidget#centralwidget{
    background-color: rgb(54, 54, 54);
}</string>
   </property>
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_2">
    <property name="spacing">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="leftMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="topMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="rightMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <property name="bottomMargin">
     <number>0</number>
    </property>
    <item>
     <widget class="QFrame" name="frame">
      <property name="styleSheet">
       <string notr="true">QFrame{
    border: 0px solid rgb(255, 255, 255)
}</string>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShape">
       <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
      </property>
      <property name="frameShadow">
       <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
      </property>
      <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout" stretch="0">
       <item alignment="Qt::AlignLeft">
        <widget class="QFrame" name="frame_7">
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Expanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShape">
          <enum>QFrame::StyledPanel</enum>
         </property>
         <property name="frameShadow">
          <enum>QFrame::Raised</enum>
         </property>
         <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout_8">
          <property name="spacing">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="leftMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="topMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="rightMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <property name="bottomMargin">
           <number>0</number>
          </property>
          <item alignment="Qt::AlignLeft">
           <widget class="QPushButton" name="btn_comments">
            <property name="sizePolicy">
             <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
              <horstretch>0</horstretch>
              <verstretch>0</verstretch>
             </sizepolicy>
            </property>
            <property name="font">
             <font>
              <family>Font Awesome 5 Free Solid</family>
              <pointsize>29</pointsize>
              <kerning>true</kerning>
             </font>
            </property>
            <property name="cursor">
             <cursorShape>PointingHandCursor</cursorShape>
            </property>
            <property name="styleSheet">
             <string notr="true">QPushButton{
    color: rgb(28, 130, 255);
    background-color:none;
    border:none;
    outline:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

QPushButton:hover{
    color: rgb(30, 148, 232);
}</string>
            </property>
            <property name="text">
             <string>comments</string>
            </property>
            <property name="flat">
             <bool>true</bool>
            </property>
           </widget>
          </item>
         </layout>
        </widget>
       </item>
      </layout>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

**badge.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>94</width>
    <height>20</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>3</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>20</width>
     <height>20</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Font Awesome 5 Free Solid</family>
     <pointsize>12</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QLabel#label_2{
    border-radius: 5px;
    color:rgb(170, 0, 0);
}</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>circle</string>
   </property>
   <property name="alignment">
    <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="label">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>10</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>21</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="font">
    <font>
     <family>Arial</family>
     <pointsize>7</pointsize>
     <weight>75</weight>
     <bold>true</bold>
    </font>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QLabel#label{
    color:rgb(255, 255, 255)
}</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>8</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Btw.
The code from above i did not edited after removing the not needed parts.
Is that ok?
let me know if you need something else.

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! Please take your time to review the [tour], read [ask], and consider that you should always create questions after careful reviewing: if your question is incomplete, don't rush it, wait until you can provide a *good* question (and possibly a valid [mre]) and then post it. That said, from what you're describing it seems that you're not properly using [layout managers](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) and/or you're not setting the [central widget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html#qt-main-window-framework).

Comment: Hello and thank your respond. I forgot... In the parent I use a layout witch I made with the qt designer. The child is just a badge witch is not in a separate layout. Maybe I can post a code in half an hour. Thank you very much

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't found a solution yet. I tried much but nothing works. There is nothing that change the situation. Always the same output.

Comment: Sorry, but that is *not* a MRE, you're just showing 2 base classes but the issue here is clearly in the UI (which you didn't provide), and without that your code is useless. Also, please review the [tour] and read [ask]. As said, take your time, don't rush a question. Ensure that anybody reading it could understand it and eventually reproduce the problem in order to see if they can help you. Try to put yourself in our shoes, imagining that you know *nothing* about your problem: are you able to understand the question and *see* the problem?

Comment: For sure. But I was not sure if I should post these huge file which was generated by the Qt creator. I will keep in mind what you say for the future

Comment: The whole point of a MRE is to *reduce* the problem to the minimum code while keeping it reproducible. Create copies of the UI files (not the pyuic generated scripts), then try to remove all parts that are not important for the problem while still allowing you to reproduce the issue. Then provide *those* UI files (again, *not* the pyuic files). In this way we have a proper *minimal* and *reproducible* example, and you don't lose the original contents of your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've often wondered what the preferred method of handling widgets that overlap. The easiest way I could think of is to put all of the overlapping elements into a single container, like a QWidget or a QFrame. I did a layout in Designer, using a QWidget as a container:

overlap1.ui

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>262</width>
    <height>344</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <layout class="QVBoxLayout" name="verticalLayout">
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_2">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Logged in:</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <layout class="QHBoxLayout" name="horizontalLayout">
      <item>
       <widget class="QWidget" name="widget" native="true">
        <property name="minimumSize">
         <size>
          <width>52</width>
          <height>32</height>
         </size>
        </property>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="lblNumMsg">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>8</x>
           <y>2</y>
           <width>16</width>
           <height>16</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>5</width>
           <height>5</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string>0</string>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="lblBubble">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>1</x>
           <y>1</y>
           <width>51</width>
           <height>31</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="sizePolicy">
          <sizepolicy hsizetype="MinimumExpanding" vsizetype="MinimumExpanding">
           <horstretch>0</horstretch>
           <verstretch>0</verstretch>
          </sizepolicy>
         </property>
         <property name="minimumSize">
          <size>
           <width>51</width>
           <height>31</height>
          </size>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="pixmap">
          <pixmap>bubble.png</pixmap>
         </property>
         <property name="scaledContents">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <widget class="QLabel" name="lblCircle">
         <property name="geometry">
          <rect>
           <x>5</x>
           <y>0</y>
           <width>16</width>
           <height>21</height>
          </rect>
         </property>
         <property name="text">
          <string/>
         </property>
         <property name="pixmap">
          <pixmap>red_circle.png</pixmap>
         </property>
         <property name="scaledContents">
          <bool>true</bool>
         </property>
        </widget>
        <zorder>lblBubble</zorder>
        <zorder>lblCircle</zorder>
        <zorder>lblNumMsg</zorder>
       </widget>
      </item>
      <item>
       <spacer name="horizontalSpacer">
        <property name="orientation">
         <enum>Qt::Horizontal</enum>
        </property>
        <property name="sizeHint" stdset="0">
         <size>
          <width>40</width>
          <height>20</height>
         </size>
        </property>
       </spacer>
      </item>
     </layout>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_3">
      <property name="text">
       <string>To User</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_6">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Subject</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_2"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLabel" name="label_4">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Message</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QLineEdit" name="lineEdit_3"/>
    </item>
    <item>
     <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
      <property name="text">
       <string>Send</string>
      </property>
     </widget>
    </item>
   </layout>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>262</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

I used these PNG files for the speech bubbles and red circle:

bubble.png

[image]

red_circle.png

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is what i need. I wasn't aware that you can assign a QWidget to a QFrame in the qt designer. That makes it easier.
I probably overlooked that.
Thank you.